# Insert x rows from variable in find

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to insert a variable amount of rows based on the # that's within a certain search phrase.

Example: If a cell in column A contains `"(4 SHEETS)"` then `3` rows would be copied below (so a total of 4 rows). Then continue to find the next match.

This is what i have so far.

```
Sub ExpandRows()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim aCell As Range
Dim i As Integer

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("test")

With ws
    Set aCell = .Columns(1).find(What:=i & " SHEETS)", LookIn:=xlValues, _
                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        aCell.EntireRow.Copy
        aCell.Offset(i).EntireRowInsert Shift:=xlDown
    End If
End With
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

*Result of code is nothing*

Comment: You haven't given `i` a value (so it's zero).

Comment: Also, you need an opening parenthesis: `...find(What:="(" & i & " SHEETS)", ...`